# Código sempre retorna o ultimo caractere?

Tags: javascript

Possuo o seguinte código

```
var browserType = 'mozillad';
var browserType2 = browserType[browserType.length-1];

document.write(browserType2);
```

Porque ele retorna *d* ele está retornando o ultimo caractere mais me expliquem porque colocar browserType dentro dos parenteses e depois utilizar a propriedade length para *-1* e depois vai resultar nisso

Comment: Leandro, se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Vc só pode aceitar uma delas, mas não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Answer (score 5):

A variável `browserType` contém uma String `'mozillad'`. Em JavaScript podes medir o comprimento de uma string (o numero de caracteres) acedendo à propriedade `.length` da mesma. Neste caso fazendo `console.log('mozillad'.length);` dá `8`.

Em JavaScript, para aceder a um desses caracteres pode usar-se  `'texto'[posiçãoDoCaracter]`, ou seja `'mozillad'[0]` vai retornar a primeira letra `m`. O que pode ser confuso aqui é que o índice para a primeira letra é `0`, e não `1`. Isto é uma característica da linguagem. E seguindo o mesmo raciocínio para ir buscar a ultima letra podes usar `'mozillad'[7]`. E, de novo, repara que aqui usamos `7` e não `8` porque começamos no zero.

Assim o teu código na prática é:

```
'mozillad'[8 - 1]
```

que é exatamente `console.log('mozillad'[7]);`, ou seja: `d`

Comment: valeu exemplo bem explicado obrigado

Answer (score 4):

`.length`, quando usada em uma string (nesse caso, `'mozzilad'`), retorna o número de caracteres dessa string. `'mozzilad'` possui 8 caracteres, portando `browserType.length - 1` é igual a 8 - 1 = 7.

Por estar acessando browserType como uma array, utilizando o índice `browserType.length-1`, `browserType[browserType.length-1]` irá retornar o 8º caractere, que está no índice 7 da array.

```js
              0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 // Índices da array
              1º 2º 3º 4º 5º 6º 7º 8º // browserType possui 8 caracteres
browserType: [m, o, z, z, i, l, a, d]
                                   ^ // Caractere a ser retornado
```

Lembrando que os índices de array começam a contar do 0 (índice 0, índice 1, etc), e o número de caracteres começa do 1 (1º caractere, 2º caracteres, etc), por isso o -1 é colocado no `.length`.

Comment: Obrigado ajudou muito abração

Comment: `+1` - boa ideia de adicionar os índices ao lado das letras

Comment: Obrigado, eu costumo entender mais facilmente quando há uma representação "visual" da explicação, então tento colocá-las em minhas repostas quando vejo que pode ajudar no entendimento

Answer (score 0):

Está retornando d pq vc está acessando o último caracter
BrowserType[índice do arry em inteiro] q no caso acima é
BrowserType.length -1 que é total de posições -1